# Is it possible to have a transparent window while having opaque children?

Tags: wxpython

My goal is to create a window that has a variable level of transparency and no standard border. On top of that area I would like to display opaque items, especially text, that might need to be made transparent. I have tried using SetTransparency methods, SetBackgroundColor and wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW styles but haven't had any luck in essentially keeping the children transparency level independent from the parent window's. I have started looking into the graphic and draw methods but not sure if this result is even possible to implement in wxPython. Should I be using a different tool or can this be achieved in wxPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxPython does not support this behavior. You might be able to fake it by creating lots of custom widgets or by drawing everything, but it will be a lot of work. You would be better off switching to a different toolkit that has this sort of thing builtin. wxPython is for developers that want to make applications that look native on the target OS.

Comment: I was expressing my entire goal at the moment but to put it more simply, is there any way to make a window's background transparent (variable or not) without setting transparency for the entire window and its children? I did a lot of trial and error but background color and such without any luck but I see many discussions about bitmap transparency which I did not try.

Comment: I never found a way to set transparency on a widget by widget basis. In wxPython, it's basically an all or nothing affair. A few of the custom widgets support a little transparency (Platebutton, AquaButton), but that's really it unless you draw it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It appears that Qt allows for this so moving over to one of the associated Python libraries.